# Which one is view-binding?

Tags: kotlin, onclicklistener, android-viewbinding

This is the code showing for me:

```
fun onclick(view: android.view.View)

fun onclick(view: View)
```

What's the difference between these.

Comment: There is no difference between the two method signatures. android.view.View is the object class for View objects. It could be that in your code you have an import statement for this class, which does not require the full path. I don't understand how this relates to view binding.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.  For the first you wrote it with the package extension and the other is a plain version.

Plain version : `fun onclick(view: View)`